# How to get a value from label and put in document.getElementById('label').innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, google-maps

I have copied JavaScript google Maps and it works perfect, but I need to get the type of html control and set it to JavaScript. When I'm trying to get value from lblTitle it doesn't work.

```
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Google Maps Geocoding Demo 1</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
//var address = 'Warsaw, PL'; Original var
                    var address = document.getElementById('lblTitle').innerText;
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                        zoom: 15
                    });

                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                    geocoder.geocode({
                        'address': address
                    },
                    function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                map: map
                            });
                            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        }
                    });

                </script>
```

Comment: What exatcly didnt work?

Comment: Given your title and description I assume it doesn't show up because address is empty? Can you alert address to verify the address is not read from the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innerText is one of the ways to retrieve text content and like most of the ways it isn't supported in all browsers. If I am correct innerText isn't supported in Firefox, so if you are testing in Firefox that might be the reason why you can't read the value.

What you should do is use JQuery's text() method to get the value, since this has max cross browser support, so you don't need to find out which browser uses which property. So in your example:

```
var address = $("#lblTitle").text();
```

If this still doesn't give you the text, then check your html in your browser to see whether the id is actually lblTitle. If you have a server control of type Label with ID lblTitle like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" />
```

then your client-side id will not be lblTitle, but it will be prefixed. The actual id on the client can be requested by using the property ClientID. So your line in javascript should be:

```
var address = $("#<%= lblTitle.ClientID %>").text();
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. My label lblTitle looks like yours. I forgot to mention that I have masterpage and when I'm editing HTML, code value "ID=lblTitle" changes to "ID=ContentPlaceHolder3_lblTitle".

Comment: That's why you should use lblTitle.ClientID like what I suggested additionally at the end of my post. That will result in your javascript looking for id "ContentPlaceHolder3_lblTitle".

Comment: I used var address = '<%=lblTitle.Text%>'; I was trying solve the problem with yours solution but it still didn't work. Thanks for help.